# Is it necessary to avoid memory leak when returning pointer by using shared_ptr?

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management

I have two functions for converting char array from gb2321 to utf-8 like,

```
#include <windows.h>
#include "memory.h"
#include <wchar.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

//GB2312 to UTF-8
char* G2U(const char* gb2312)
{
    int len = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, gb2312, -1, NULL, 0);
    wchar_t* wstr = new wchar_t[len + 1];
    memset(wstr, 0, len + 1);
    MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, gb2312, -1, wstr, len);
    len = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, wstr, -1, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);
    char* str = new char[len + 1];

    //what about using shared_ptr to release resource but how to modify following code?  
    //shared_ptr<char> str(new char[len + 1], default_delete<char[]>());

    memset(str, 0, len + 1);
    WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, wstr, -1, str, len, NULL, NULL);
    if (wstr) delete[] wstr;
    return str;
}
```

I read this code part in website and I was wondering if I should replace  `char* str = new char[len + 1];` with `shared_ptr`. If so, how to modify the following code, `memset` and `WideCharToMultiByte`? P.S, is there some method used by `C` not `CPP` ?

Comment: You can use `std::vector<char> str` instead. `shared_ptr<char>` will not do. You could use `shared_ptr<char[]>` but I don't see an advantage of this over `std::vector<char>`. In `WideCharToMultiByte` you can use `str.data()` to get a `char*`.

Comment: @wohlstad Or just `string` and `wstring`?

Comment: @Ranoiaetep I guess `string` can also be used. But since the OP used a raw C array which is passes to a legacy Win32 API, `std::vector` is the closest equivalent.

Comment: @wohlstad You can get the same C array through `string::data()`

Comment: @Ranoiaetep but isn't `std::string` less flexible than `std::vector` when it comes to controlling size and capacity ? I never used `std::string` with legacy APIs like `WideCharToMultiByte ` requiring a char* . Please post an answer demonstrating it.

Comment: @wohlstad Just like a `vector`, you can always call `reserve` on `string`. And for both `vector` and `string`, you should probably fill them through `T(len, 0)`, instead of calling `fill` manually after creation.

Comment: @Ranoiaetep good to know - thanks for the info about `std::string`. Since my answer was using `std::vector` I kept it like that but modified it to avoid `std::fill` as you suggested.

Comment: @4daJKong I added `c++` tag since `shared_ptr` is available only in c++. c has no automatic heap memory management mechanism.

Comment: Please don't tag irrelevant languages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of managing a raw pointer, or even a `shared_ptr` to manage a `char` pointer, you can simply use [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).
It has a [constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) that accepts a size and a value (thus you don't need `memset`).  You can use [`std::vector::data`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/data) to access the underlying data buffer.

Below you can see an example for `str`. A similar solution can be applied to `wstr`.

```
#include <vector>

std::vector<char> str(len + 1, 0);  // allocate size and set all elements to 0
//----------------------------------------vvvvvvvvvv
WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, wstr, -1, str.data(), len, NULL, NULL);
```

**Note:**
In general it could be more straightforward using `std::string`. But until C++17 `std::string::data` returns a `const char*` which is incompatible with the Win32 API pointer which is used to write data into.
You can still return `std::string` from your `G2U` function, by using:

```
return std::string(str.begin(), str.end());
```

If you can use C++17 you can use `std::string` instead of `std::vector<char>` and then you will be able to return `str` directly.

**Update:**
Regarding the "P.S." at the end of your question - as far as I know the **c** language has no mechanism for automatic heap memory management.

Comment: Can I use `if(str) delete[]  wstr`? the only problem is how to use if after return value

Comment: You can. But if you make `wstr` a `std::vector<wchar_t>` (similarly to the way I did it for `str`) you will not need any `delete`.

Comment: Also since you need to return a string from your function, see the comments above about using `std::string` as a direct replacement for `std::vector`. In this case you can simply return a `std::string` from your function.

Comment: Sorry, the problem is... it is better to avoid using c++ method, because it would be used in DLL

Comment: I modified my answer to show the usage of `std::string`, In this case you can simply change the return value of `G2U` to `std::string` and return `str`.

Comment: If you want to avoid using c++ the whole question regarding `std::shared_ptr` is irrelevant. Also `new` is c++ only.

Comment: c and c++ are very different. If you need a c solution I suggest you post a new question. However - as I wrote I believe c has no mechanism for automatic heap memory management.

Comment: thank you so much! I am a novice in cpp and c, there are lots of things made me confused...

Comment: Hi, I follow you code but is shows `argument of type "const char * is incompatible with parameter of type "LPSTR""`, and is it avaiable input is a char* while output is string?

Comment: See an update to my answer, using `std::vector` instead of `std::string`.

Comment: If you can use C++ 17 you can use the `std::string` solution as is.